# How to use Comparator<Object> for Ascending, Descending without sorting

Tags: java, android, comparable

I try to get an answer but every question about Comparators deals with sorting.

Im trying to use a Comparator with values from `dog.getAge()`

My class look like

```
public final class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>{
...
@Override
    public int compare(Dog o1, Dog o2) {
        if (o1.getAge() > o2.getAge()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o2.getAge() > o1.getAge()) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And in main activity i try compare the dogs, but i think the problem  is Iam dont know how to end this method,

Also i got an error:  `Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.`

I am trying to get dogs from api.

So here is my method in MainActivity

```
private List<Dog> dogsArray = new ArrayList<>();

private void checkAscendingOrDescendingDogsAge() {
        Dog dog= new Dog();
        for (int i = 0; i < dogsArray.size(); i++) {
            dog.compare(dogsArray.get(i), dogsArray.get(i + 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So... you want to check whether the dog's ages in `dogsArray` are ordered ascendingly or descendingly?

Comment: No. Iam wants to check that the dog's age is bigger than previous or less

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. And for the record: you might want to write up a **new** specific question regarding that scheduler exception. I guess it doesn't have anything to do with the "core" of this question, so I didn't talk about that at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what your intended use is; this here:

```
if (o1.getAge() > o2.getAge()) {
  return 1;
} else if (o2.getAge() > o1.getAge()) {
  return 2;
}
```

is incorrect. The idea is that `compareTo()` returns negative, equal zero , positive results. There is no point in deciding for yourself that you want to change the contract of that method to say: 1 for o1 older than o2; and 2 for o2 older than o1. This interface, and that method have a **well defined** contract, and you simply stick to that. Unless your goal is to mislead your readers on purpose. But be assured, that will bite back on you quickly.

Assuming that `getAge()` returns, say int, you simply replace that with:

```
 return Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge())
```

And then the **trick** is to define **additional** methods such as:

```
public boolean isOlder(Dog other) {
  return compareTo(this, other) > 0;
```

for example.

And you use that like:

```
Dog buddy = new Dog(...
Dog sparky = new Dog(...

if (buddy.isOlder(sparky)
```

Comment: And how now i can use this method in MainActivity?
Dog dog1 = new Dog():
Dog dog2 = new Dog();
dog2 = dogsArray.get(dogposition).getAge();

dog1.callMethod(dog2):

Comment: I see you saw my updates. But please note: you have to pay attention on subtle details, such as: what do you expect `isOlder()` to return when both dogs have the same age? My code is mainly meant as inspiration to show how things *could* be done.

Comment: I want to give information when the age of next dog is bigger by 1 or smaller by 1, for example dogage =11 dogsage2 = 12(bigger) i will try on my way, but if u have some time you can edit your answer. Anyway, thanks for quick and nice answer.

Comment: I think you are approaching this one the wrong level. If you have **more** than 2 dog objects, then you do NOT start writing complicated if a > b else if b > c ... code. Instead: you put those objects into a list; and then you sort that list. Seriously: do not do such things manually. Sort the list; and when you iterate the list front to end, you get ascending; and when you iterate the sorted list end to front, you get descending. It is that simple.

Comment: I trying to sort it, but my task is to get 5 dogs on start application(and every dog is random), im declared them in RecyclerView, next with button i can get next dogs and next up to 120 of dogs. My task is: a minimum of 3 dogs age are in ascending / descending

Comment: You should step back; and maybe first work on this code *without* thinking about Android. Meaning: there is really nothing special about it: you create an empty list, you add *n* random dogs to that; you sort it. You can then add more dogs; and sort again. As said: as soon as you are dealing with more than two distinct objects, you dont treat them with special code. In other words: your dogs aren't pets. They should not have names! They are cattle, they only have a **number** that identifies them (as index in a list/array)!